# Ansible replace module with no_log still spams console

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to replace a large number of files using the Ansible replace module:

```
  - name: gather all file names
    find:
      paths: "{{ path }}"
      recurse: yes
      excludes: '*.so,*.class,*.jar'
    register: allFiles

  - name: tag all files with version number
    replace:
      path: "{{item.path}}"
      regexp: '<< version >>'
      replace: '{{ version_number }}'
    with_items:
      - "{{allFiles.files}}"
    no_log: True
```

However, even with no_log set to True, the console gets flooded with messages like this:

```
changed: [host] => (item=None)
changed: [host] => (item=None)
changed: [host] => (item=None)
changed: [host] => (item=None)
changed: [host] => (item=None)
changed: [host] => (item=None)
changed: [host] => (item=None)
changed: [host] => (item=None)
```

Is it possible to remove this spam? Or alternatively, is it possible to change it from item=None to item=file_name.txt so I can at least see something useful in the log? If I turn off no_log, I get multiple lines of unnecessary information, I'd prefer to either see nothing, or see just item=filename.txt

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[`no_log` is intended to prevent sensitive data from being shown in logs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html#protecting-sensitive-data-with-no-log), not to avoid printing tasks on the console.

To control loop labels, you should instead use [`loop_control`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label):

```yaml
  - name: tag all files with version number
    replace:
      path: '{{ item.path }}'
      regexp: << version >>
      replace: '{{ version_number }}'
    loop: '{{ allFiles.files }}'
    loop_control:
      label: '{{ item.path }}'
```

Or, since you're only using the filename and don't need the rest of the data, you can loop over just the filenames and then the default label will be smaller:

```yaml
  - name: tag all files with version number
    replace:
      path: '{{ item }}'
      regexp: << version >>
      replace: '{{ version_number }}'
    loop: '{{ allFiles.files | map(attribute="path") }}'
```

To get rid of the output entirely, you would need to find or write a [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_callback.html) that provides the output verbosity you want.